# Defining what html tag to follow another given html tag with TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce

I want to define an html tag to follow another tag. E.g. if I insert a **dt** tag and hit return, I'd like it to insert a **dd** and vice versa in the same way it defaults to a **p** tag following a heading tag. Is this something built into TinyMCE? Or something that can be achieved simply otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about inserting your tags by keyboard directly into the editor.
There is nothing prebuilt inside tinymce with this functionality. You will have to write your own plugin and check for each keyboard press if dt or dd has been inserted. Then you will have to replace dt&dd with the tag you wish.
This insertion will have to take place manipulating the dom (and not the editors text).

Be aware that you will need to take care that dt- and dd- tags don't get cleaned out by setting the [custom_element](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE%3aConfiguration/custom_elements)s in your configuration.